# Colab not asking for 25GB ram after 12GB ram crashed

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Usually, colab allocates us 25GB ram when we crash 12GB ram. But in my case, it is not asking or allocating 25GB ram.

```
a = []
while (1):
 a.append(1)
```

I ran this program to crash. It is crashing but it says, “colab crashed after using all ram, see runtime logs” and then restarts.

Runtime is GPU

what might be the problem here?

Comment: It might be a problem with your browser (I highly doubt it), but try to 
Ctrl + Shift + F5 to Reload your page, ignoring cached content

Comment: I tried with both chrome and firefox but same issue

Answer (score 1):

Related: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/1246

Quoting this:

> Resources are not guaranteed may vary over time. For more context,
>   see: https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html#resource-limits